# Cause of nullpointer

Tags: java

Hello I have been trying to figure out this error for quite some time now. I'm having a newby problem with a nullpointer here is the class:

Edit: The program is meant to inject code into another class to stop it from removing classes when it is loaded then it reflects the class files (stored as byte arrays) and then dumps to a class file.

I have commented the line number that corresponds to the stack trace

```
public class Program {

private HashMap<String, ClassGen> myClass = new HashMap<String, ClassGen>();
private int array_index;

/**
 * Constructor.
 */
public Program() {
    try {
        File Jar1 = new File("Jar1.jar");
        File nJar1 = new File("nJar1.jar");
        File OutPutJar = new File("Out.jar");
        BAppletStub stub = new BAppletStub();
        injectLoader();
        dumpClientFiles(stub); // Line 65
        JarFile theJar = new JarFile(OutPutJar);
        Enumeration<?> en = theJar.entries();
        while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
            JarEntry entry = (JarEntry) en.nextElement();
            if (entry.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
                ClassParser cp = new ClassParser(theJar.getInputStream(entry), entry.getName());
                JavaClass jc = cp.parse();
                ClassGen cg = new ClassGen(jc);
                myClass.put(cg.getClassName(), cg);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void injectLoader() throws IOException {
    JarFile theJar = new JarFile("Jar1.jar");
    FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("nJar1.jar");
    JarOutputStream out = new JarOutputStream(stream);
    Enumeration<?> en = theJar.entries();
    while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
        JarEntry entry = (JarEntry) en.nextElement();
        if (entry.getName().contains("META-INF"))
            continue;
        JarEntry je = new JarEntry(entry.getName());
        out.putNextEntry(je);
        if (entry.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
            ClassParser cp = new ClassParser(theJar.getInputStream(entry), entry.getName());
            JavaClass jc = cp.parse();
            ClassGen cg = new ClassGen(jc);
            fixClass(cg);
            out.write(cg.getJavaClass().getBytes());
        } else {
            InputStream in = theJar.getInputStream(entry);
            int read;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        }
    }
    out.close();
    stream.close();
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "unchecked" })
private void fixClass(ClassGen cg) {
    for (Method m : cg.getMethods()) {
        if (m.getReturnType().equals(Type.CLASS)) {
            MethodGen mg = new MethodGen(m, cg.getClassName(), cg.getConstantPool());
            InstructionList list = mg.getInstructionList();
            String pattern = "aaload checkcast aload invokevirtual";
            InstructionFinder finder = new InstructionFinder(list);
            Iterator<InstructionHandle[]> it = finder.search(pattern);
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                InstructionHandle[] handles = it.next();
                INVOKEVIRTUAL invoke = (INVOKEVIRTUAL) handles[3].getInstruction();
                if (invoke.getMethodName(cg.getConstantPool()).equals("remove") && invoke.getClassName(cg.getConstantPool()).contains("Hashtable")) {
                    InstructionFactory factory = new InstructionFactory(cg);
                    Instruction i = factory.createInvoke("java/util/Hashtable", "get", invoke.getReturnType(cg.getConstantPool()), invoke.getArgumentTypes(cg.getConstantPool()), Constants.INVOKEVIRTUAL);
                    InstructionHandle handle = list.insert(handles[3], i);
                    InstructionHandle h = handles[3];
                    if (h.hasTargeters()) {
                        for (InstructionTargeter t : h.getTargeters()) {
                            t.updateTarget(h, handle);
                        }
                    }
                    try {
                        list.delete(h);
                    } catch (TargetLostException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mg.setMaxLocals();
                    mg.setMaxStack();
                    cg.replaceMethod(m, mg.getMethod());
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void dumpClientFiles(BAppletStub stub) {
    try {
        File f = new File("nJar1.jar");
        URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { f.toURI().toURL() });
        Class<?> g = loader.loadClass("Rs2Applet");
        final Applet a = (Applet) g.newInstance();
        a.setStub(stub);
        a.init();
        Object[] objs = getObjects(g, a); // Line 237
        if (objs == null)
            System.exit(1);
        Hashtable<?, ?> tempTable = (Hashtable<?, ?>) objs[array_index];
        JarOutputStream out = new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Out.jar"));
        Enumeration<?> it = tempTable.keys();
        int classes_dumped = 0;
        while (it.hasMoreElements()) {
            String s = (String) it.nextElement();
            Object o = tempTable.get(s);
            JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(s.replace(".", "/") + ".class");
            out.putNextEntry(entry);
            out.write((byte[]) o);
            out.closeEntry();
            classes_dumped++;
        }
        System.out.println("Dumped " + classes_dumped + " classes to Out.jar");
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Object[] getObjects(Class<?> clazz, Object object) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    Field fd = null;
    Field arr = null;
    for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
        if ((field.getModifiers() & Modifier.PRIVATE) != 0 && field.getType().getCanonicalName().equals("java.lang.Object[]")) {
            if (fd == null) {
                fd = field;
            } else {
                arr = field;
            }
        }
    }
    Object[] objs = null;
    boolean found = false;
    Field array_field = null;
    outer: for (int i = 0; i < 2 && !found; i++) {
        array_field = (array_field == null || array_field == arr) ? fd : arr;
        if (!array_field.isAccessible()) { //Line 278
            array_field.setAccessible(true);
        }
        objs = (Object[]) array_field.get(object);
        for (int j = 0; j < objs.length; j++) {
            Object o = objs[j];
            if (o instanceof Hashtable) {
                found = true;
                if (((Hashtable<?, ?>) o).values().iterator().next().getClass().getCanonicalName().equals("byte[]")) {
                    array_index = j;
                    break outer;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (fd.isAccessible())
        fd.setAccessible(false);
    if (arr.isAccessible())
        arr.setAccessible(false);
    return objs;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Program(); //Line 304
}
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.nick.program.getObjects(program.java:278)
at org.nick.program.dumpFiles(program.java:237)
at org.nick.program.<init>(program.java:65)
at org.nick.program.main(program.java:304)
```

My question is what is causing the nullpointer and how could I correct it?

Comment: It will also helpful if you include the stacktrace here.

Comment: Could you show the stack trace?

Comment: If you post the full exception stack trace you get as well it will be easier to debug.

Comment: Doesn't it give you a stack trace with the exact line number that the issue happened on?

Comment: Provide Exception trace to help you resolve the issue.

Comment: yeah, the stacktrace and the line that is throwing the exception!

Comment: it looks like `array_field` is never set to value other than `null`, meaning that both `fd` and `arr` stays null. check your if condition for setting these variables

Comment: The code calling your method could also be useful.

Answer (score 5):

If `clazz` doesn't contain any private fields of type `Object[]` (and *exactly* `Object[]`!  Type erasure may come into play, but inheritance doesn't), neither `fd` nor `arr` will be set.  The line that sets `array_field` assumes that if `arr` isn't set, `fd` will be -- but in the case just mentioned, it won't be.

As for how to fix it...well, that depends on what exactly you're trying to do.  The code doesn't make much sense to me at the moment, so a description of what it *should* be doing would help immensely.

Comment: Thanks for your swift response I have updated my thread to try and give out some more information :)

Comment: @Nicholas: I meant, what exactly is `getObjects` supposed to be doing?  It's apparently not just getting objects.

Comment: Searches every method which returns type class

Comment: Erm...far as i can tell, it doesn't even come close to doing that.  For one, it's working with Fields and not Methods.  For another, you're checking for the type `Object[]`, not a particular class's name.

Answer (score 1):

There's many methods in your code that may cause this `NullPointerException`.

For example, at line 5:

`field.getType().getCanonicalName().equals` may cause this problem as [`getCanonicalName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getCanonicalName%28%29) may return `null` and best way in this case is to use: 
`"java.lang.Object[]".equals(field.getType().getCanonicalName())`

Although, this is not the problem, you have to use defensive programming as illustrated above (or at least check for `nulls`).

Comment: The class is apparently being loaded by name, so it pretty much has to have a canonical name.

Comment: I agree with you, I just want to tell him that he have to defense his own programs (I've edited my answer)